# Vue Async component importing not working in history mode of cordova applications

Tags: cordova, vue.js, vue-router

Recently I am supporting history mode to my **vue.js** based application. I am using a web-pack to build my application and creating chunks based on my requirements with the following code snippet. I am importing a few of my components async. Unfortunately async component importing not working in history mode only in Cordova based application. It was working in the browser not sure why it was not working in Cordova based applications.

Field component, where I am importing field-inner component async

```
<template>
  <FormFieldInner></FormFieldInner>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    field: Object,
  },
  data() {
 },
  components: {
FormFieldInner: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "form-field-inner" */'@/components/form/FormFieldInner.vue'),
  },
};
</script>
```

Error Which I am getting 
[image]

FYI: Form not rendering in Cordova application it was working in the browser. Vue application which is supporting history mode. Can anyone help me?